# What is "reliable write" in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

In Android's BLE API ([BluetoothGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html)) there are methods that deal with **reliable writes**:

```
public boolean beginReliableWrite ()

public void abortReliableWrite (BluetoothDevice mDevice)

public boolean executeReliableWrite ()
```

There is also a Callback for it (in [BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onReliableWriteCompleted%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int%29)):

```
public void onReliableWriteCompleted (BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
```

I can't find any documentation on that. What is it? How is it different from "normal" (unreliable?) writes?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Reliable write allows checking back transmitted values and atomic execution of one or mutliple transmitted messages.

A good explaination of the reliable write procedure can be found in the [BLE part of Mozillas Boot 2 Gecko Project documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Bluetooth/WebBluetooth-v2/BluetoothGatt). Even though it's meant for JavaScript the description of `beginReliableWrite()` in particular is very helpful for understanding the process:

> Once a reliable write transaction has been initiated, all calls to
>   characteristic.writeValue() are sent to the remote device for
>   verification and queued up for atomic execution. An Promise that
>   carries the written value is returned in response to every
>   characteristic.writeValue() call and the application is responsible
>   for verifying whether the value has been transmitted accurately. After
>   all characteristics have been queued up and verified,
>   executeReliableWrite() will execute all writes. If a characteristic
>   was not written correctly, calling abortReliableWrite() will cancel
>   the current transaction without committing any values on the remote LE
>   device.

You begin the reliable write,

```
gatt.beginReliableWrite();
```

set the value of the characteristic and write it.

```
characteristic.setValue(value);
gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

The `writeCharacteristic()` call will trigger its 'normal' callback. The parameter `characteristic` contains the actual, written value which can be verified:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, 
                int status) {
    ...

    if(characteristic.getValue() != value) { 
        gatt.abortReliableWrite();
    } else {
        gatt.executeReliableWrite();
    }

    ...
}
```

Executing the reliable write will trigger the `onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)` callback.

Comment: characteristic.getValue() != value does not compare the contents but rather the memory addresses of the arrays, which is wrong. Anyway, reliable writes in android are currently broken since getValue() does not return the value sent by the server, which is against what the documentation says.

Comment: we can simply modify the comparison of characteristic values using `.contentEquals()`